# How to represent Complex plane regions in SymPy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have recently started using SymPy, I know there are real intervals in it to represent regions in complex plane, but is there something we can do to represent regions in complex plain?

For example: Represent a disk of radius 2 in upper two quadrants in the complex plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can represent regions of Complex Plane in SymPy, but that's currently not available in any release. You have to use the latest git version for that: https://github.com/sympy/sympy.git

This can be done using `ComplexPlane` class:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: init_printing()

In [3]: ComplexRegion(Interval(0, 2)*Interval(0, pi), polar=True)
Out[3]: {r⋅(ⅈ⋅sin(θ) + cos(θ)) | r, θ ∊ [0, 2] × [0, π]}

In [4]: ComplexRegion(Interval(-oo, oo)*Interval(0, oo))
Out[4]: {x + ⅈ⋅y | x, y ∊ (-∞, ∞) × [0, ∞)}
```

You may like to read this blog post about this functionality: http://iamit.in/blog/GSoC-week-3/